# Alter the collation of a column in temp-file

Tags: sql-server, collation, tempdb, temporary-tables

I have a routine in a DB that uses a temp-file. But the collation of the DB doesn't match the collation of the temp-DB. I can't change the collation of the DB, it's a client DB.
I tried this:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @Collation sysname;
SELECT @Collation=collation_name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = DB_NAME();

CREATE TABLE #Resultaten
(Supplier smallint,
Productcode varchar(20) COLLATE @Collation;,...)
...
```

but that doesn't work.

Is there a way to match the collation of a column of a temp-file with the collation of the current DB?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want the `database_default` option:

```
CREATE TABLE #Resultaten
(
   Supplier smallint NULL,
   Productcode varchar(20) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NULL,
   ...
)
```

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations).

> **database_default** Causes the COLLATE clause to inherit the collation of the current database.